# Share large spatial index across processes in python multiprocessing environment

Tags: python, indexing, multiprocessing, spatial

I have an STRtree spatial index created using ‘shapely’ in python. I want to use this spatial index in the multiprocessing environment in python. The spatial index is read-only and to be used to search input data in the spatial domain.

Since the size of the spatial index is large how can we share the spatial index for each process in the multiprocessing environment?

In pyspark there is an option to broadcast the object to a different process however, I want to use a multiprocessing environment for this purpose.

Is there a way to share large spatial index data across processes in python?